# How to conditionally use Combine @Published when minimum deployment target is set to iOS 12.2?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have an app with minimum deployment target of **iOS 12.0**. There are parts written in `SwiftUI` and `Combine`. All methods and types using the two libraries are marked with `@available(iOS 13.0, *)`. The app has been running in this mixed setup since January without problems.

To take advantage of ABI stability and reduce the app size I want to set the new minimum deployment target to **iOS 12.2**.

When I do that the app crashes on launch (iOS 12.4 simulator) with the following printed to the console:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol
> **_$s7Combine9PublishedVMa** in /Users/YYYYYYYYY/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/UUD-UUD-UUD-UUD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/UUD/XXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXX
> because dependent dylib #29 could not be loaded dyld: can't resolve
> symbol **_$s7Combine9PublishedVMa** in
> /Users/YYYYYYYYY/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/UUD-UUD-UUD-UUD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/UUD-UUD-UUD-UUD/XXXXXXXapp/XXXXXXX
> because dependent dylib #29 could not be loaded

The app also crashes when attempting to launch on iPhone running iOS 12.4.

If I remove all `@Published` from the code but leave all other `Combine` and `SwiftUI` related bits  the app can be used on iOS 12.

Even though all the classes containing `@Published` are marked with `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` I have tried wrapping them additionally in #`if canImport(Combine)` or applying `#if canImport(Combine)` to each `@Published` variable. This does not help.

I know I could change

```
@Published var name = ""
```

to

```
var name = "" {
    willSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

But that seems like a nasty workaround.

How can I increase deployment target to **iOS 12.2** and keep using `@Published` when device is running **iOS 13.0** or higher?

Comment: Did you manage to get around this? Having the same problem with optional Combine and "@Published"

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to go with removing @Published and using willSet and sending objectWillChange from there.

Comment: That's a pitty! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to weakly link the `Combine` (and `SwiftUI` if you're also using that) framework(s) to your project. You can achieve this using the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting.

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -weak_framework Combine -weak_framework SwiftUI
```

You don't actually need `canImport` statements, you only need the framework to be weakly linked. You of course still need the `@available` annotation on all types that use `Combine`.

Comment: I have done that. Sorry I forgot to mention it in my question. Without weak linking having Combine/SwiftUI and target below iOS 13 does not work at all. My problem seems to be with @Published specifically

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the property wrapper `@Published` in a deployment target lower than iOS 13. The only way to do this is as you described above.

In your class (which should conform to the `ObservableObject` protocol), instead of:

```swift
@Published var name = ""
```

You have to have:

```swift
var name = "" {
    willSet {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *) {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

You may also need to explicitly add the `objectWillChange` declaration in your class:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public lazy var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
```